# 3 levels Json how can I make a count inside

Tags: java, json

I want to consume an api that returns a json like this one:

```
{
  "startDate": "2019-06-23T16:07:21.205Z",
  "endDate": "2019-07-24T16:07:21.205Z",
  "status": "Complete",
  "usages": [
    {
      "name": "PureCloud Edge Virtual Usage",
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "Edge01-VM-GNS-DemoSite01 (1f279086-a6be-4a21-ab7a-2bb1ae703fa0)",
          "date": "2019-07-24T09:00:28.034Z"
        },
        {
          "name": "329ad5ae-e3a3-4371-9684-13dcb6542e11",
          "date": "2019-07-24T09:00:28.034Z"
        },        
        {
          "name": "e5796741-bd63-4b8e-9837-4afb95bb0c09",
          "date": "2019-07-24T09:00:28.034Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "PureCloud for SmartVideo Add-On Concurrent",
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "jpizarro@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z"
        },
        {
          "name": "jaguilera@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z"
        },        
        {
          "name": "dcortes@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-07-15T15:06:09.203Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "PureCloud 3 Concurrent User Usage",
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "jpizarro@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z"
        },
        {
          "name": "jaguilera@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z"
        },       
        {
          "name": "dcortes@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-07-15T15:06:09.203Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "PureCloud Skype for Business WebSDK",
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "jpizarro@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z"
        },
        {
          "name": "jaguilera@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z"
        },      
        {
          "name": "dcortes@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-07-15T15:06:09.203Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "selfUri": "/api/v2/billing/reports/billableusage"
}
```

I have to count the amount of name in the last level. Looking on the web I´ve found a library and I just tried to adapt the example, but I have some doubts: one is that it starts with a string, not the route of the json file I have to test. I´ve put it in there manually, buy Eclipse added a lot of: /

When I try to run this:

```
String jsonString = "{\r\n" + 
                    "  \"startDate\": \"2019-06-23T16:07:21.205Z\",\r\n" + 
                    "  \"endDate\": \"2019-07-24T16:07:21.205Z\",\r\n" + 
                    "  \"status\": \"Complete\",\r\n" + 
                    "  \"usages\": [\r\n" + 
                    "    {\r\n" + 
                    "      \"name\": \"PureCloud Edge Virtual Usage\",\r\n" + 
                    "      \"resources\": [\r\n" + 
                    "        {\r\n" + 
                    "          \"name\": \"Edge01-VM-GNS-DemoSite01 (1f279086-a6be-4a21-ab7a-2bb1ae703fa0)\",\r\n" + 
                    "          \"date\": \"2019-07-24T09:00:28.034Z\"\r\n" + 
                    "        },\r\n" + 
                    "        {\r\n" + 
                    "          \"name\": \"329ad5ae-e3a3-4371-9684-13dcb6542e11\",\r\n" + 
                    "          \"date\": \"2019-07-24T09:00:28.034Z\"\r\n" + 
                    "        },        \r\n" + 
                    "        {\r\n" + 
                    "          \"name\": \"e5796741-bd63-4b8e-9837-4afb95bb0c09\",\r\n" + 
                    "          \"date\": \"2019-07-24T09:00:28.034Z\"\r\n" + 
                    "        }\r\n" + 
                    "      ]\r\n" + 
                    "    },\r\n" + 
                    "    {\r\n" + 
                    "      \"name\": \"PureCloud for SmartVideo Add-On Concurrent\",\r\n" + 
                    "      \"resources\": [\r\n" + 
                    "        {\r\n" + 
                    "          \"name\": \"jpizarro@gns.com.co\",\r\n" + 
                    "          \"date\": \"2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z\"\r\n" + 
                    "        },\r\n" + 
                    "        {\r\n" + 
                    "          \"name\": \"jaguilera@gns.com.co\",\r\n" + 
                    "          \"date\": \"2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z\"\r\n" + 
                    "        },        \r\n" + 
                    "        {\r\n" + 
                    "          \"name\": \"dcortes@gns.com.co\",\r\n" + 
                    "          \"date\": \"2019-07-15T15:06:09.203Z\"\r\n" + 
                    "        }\r\n" + 
                    "      ]\r\n" + 
                    "    },\r\n" + 
                    "    {\r\n" + 
                    "      \"name\": \"PureCloud 3 Concurrent User Usage\",\r\n" + 
                    "      \"resources\": [\r\n" + 
                    "        {\r\n" + 
                    "          \"name\": \"jpizarro@gns.com.co\",\r\n" + 
                    "          \"date\": \"2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z\"\r\n" + 
                    "        },\r\n" + 
                    "        {\r\n" + 
                    "          \"name\": \"jaguilera@gns.com.co\",\r\n" + 
                    "          \"date\": \"2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z\"\r\n" + 
                    "        },       \r\n" + 
                    "        {\r\n" + 
                    "          \"name\": \"dcortes@gns.com.co\",\r\n" + 
                    "          \"date\": \"2019-07-15T15:06:09.203Z\"\r\n" + 
                    "        }\r\n" + 
                    "      ]\r\n" + 
                    "    },\r\n" + 
                    "    {\r\n" + 
                    "      \"name\": \"PureCloud Skype for Business WebSDK\",\r\n" + 
                    "      \"resources\": [\r\n" + 
                    "        {\r\n" + 
                    "          \"name\": \"jpizarro@gns.com.co\",\r\n" + 
                    "          \"date\": \"2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z\"\r\n" + 
                    "        },\r\n" + 
                    "        {\r\n" + 
                    "          \"name\": \"jaguilera@gns.com.co\",\r\n" + 
                    "          \"date\": \"2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z\"\r\n" + 
                    "        },      \r\n" + 
                    "        {\r\n" + 
                    "          \"name\": \"dcortes@gns.com.co\",\r\n" + 
                    "          \"date\": \"2019-07-15T15:06:09.203Z\"\r\n" + 
                    "        }\r\n" + 
                    "      ]\r\n" + 
                    "    }\r\n" + 
                    "  ],\r\n" + 
                    "  \"selfUri\": \"/api/v2/billing/reports/billableusage\"\r\n" + 
                    "}\r\n" + 
                    ""; 
            int cantidadDeLicencias = 0;
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);        
            JSONArray usages = jsonObject.getJSONArray("usages");     
            System.out.println("usages " + usages);

            for (int i = 0; i < usages.length(); i++) {
                JSONArray resources = jsonObject.getJSONArray("resources");

                for (int j = 0; j < resources.length(); j++) {
                    JSONArray names = jsonObject.getJSONArray("name");
                    cantidadDeLicencias = cantidadDeLicencias + names.length();
                    //String name = jsonObject.getJSONObject(j).getString("name");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Cantidad de licencias" + cantidadDeLicencias);
```

An error comes out: JSONObject["resources"] not found.

If the program would work, what changes I have to make cause, the api returns a json, you know, without all those: /. So this library is going to be useful?

---

Update
Now it works

```
int cantidadDeLicencias = 0;
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);        
            JSONArray usages = jsonObject.getJSONArray("usages");     
            System.out.println("usages " + usages);

            for (int i = 0; i < usages.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject innerTemp = usages.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray resources = innerTemp.getJSONArray("resources");
                //JSONArray resources = usages.getJSONArray("resources");

                for (int j = 0; j < resources.length(); j++) {
                    String names = resources.getJSONObject(j).getString("name");
                    cantidadDeLicencias = cantidadDeLicencias + 1; 
                    //String name = jsonObject.getJSONObject(j).getString("name");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Cantidad de licencias " + cantidadDeLicencias);
```

What should I do with the json? cause, here it has a lot of: / and the api doesn´t return that?

Comment: Do you actually want to be able to read all the values, or do you _only_ care about the count?

Comment: Only about the count

Comment: Then you might consider [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath): `$.usages[*].resources[*].name.length()`. I also _strongly_ recommend you learn the basics of Java (you seemed surprised at basic string representations) before starting complex projects.

Comment: I´ve just came from .net and angular and the company doesnt have time so I can review the basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resources` is inside a `JSONObject`, not directly inside the `JSONArray`.

Access it like this:

```
JSONArray usages = jsonObject.getJSONArray("usages");
for (int i = 0; i < usages.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject innerTemp = usages.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray resources = innerTemp.getJSONArray("resources");
    // more code here
}
```